# Spark to mongo db Insertion taking 10 hrs for 60Gb data

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I'm using **Spark: 1.6.2** and **MongoDB: 3.2.8**

I have a dataframe with 8 column and 1Billion rows.
shuffle write for data frame is 60GB.

I am going to insert that dataframe in mongodb using mongo-spark-conector (mongo-spark-connector_2.10).

```
MongoSpark.write(sourceValueDf).options(mongoDbOptions).mode(SaveMode.Append).save();
```

For insertions it takes more than 10hrs.

How can I increase the performance?

Comment: can you give more details on your options ? How you write it ? in bulk or 1 document each ?

Answer (score 8):

There's not much to go on with:

`MongoSpark.write(sourceValueDf).options(mongoDbOptions).mode(SaveMode.Append).save()`

But regardless of `mongoDBOptions` the tuning will need to be two fold and  performance bottlenecks will need to be fixed in Spark and MongoDB. The key to success is understanding what is happening when you run the code above, only then can you determine the best course to improving the performance.

## Spark

> I have a dataframe with 8 column and 1Billion rows. shuffle write for data frame is 60GB.

There's no information on the `sourceValueDf` but you will need to configure the source and understand is that the bottleneck?  See the [Spark Monitoring](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) documentation on how to understand more about what is happening in your Spark jobs.

In general the key points for Spark tuning are; *partitioning*, *caching*, *serialization*, and the *shuffle* operation.  For more information see this great blog post by the cloudera: [Working with Apache Spark: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Shuffle](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/05/working-with-apache-spark-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-shuffle/).  There's lots of potential take aways on how to improve Spark jobs.

## MongoDB

Let's look at what the MongoDB Spark connector will do with:

`MongoSpark.write(sourceValueDf).options(mongoDbOptions).mode(SaveMode.Append).save()`

Here the connector takes the underlying RDD and saves the data as documents in an existing database using the following logic:

```
rdd.foreachPartition(iter => if (iter.nonEmpty) {
    mongoConnector.withCollectionDo(writeConfig, { collection: MongoCollection[D] =>
    iter.grouped(DefaultMaxBatchSize).foreach(batch => collection.insertMany(batch.toList.asJava))
    })
})
```

For each partition it will batch the writes into insertMany, using 512 documents per batch (the underlying Java driver bulk batch size). Low number of partitions in the `sourceValueDf` could negatively impact performance of the save. Increasing the number of partitions may increase the parallelizability of this method across the Spark workers and therefore increase thoroughput.

There are other general methods to improve the write performance for bulk operations to MongoDB:

- **Network**

  Ensuring the Spark Workers and the MongoDB instance(s) are colocated or have as small a network hop as possible. You can't beat physics.
- **Sharding**

  Increase the parallelizability of writes by inserting to a sharded collection, especially when inserting data presorted on the shard key. Co-location of Spark workers with Sharded MongoD's can provide the fastest possible scenario for writes. See the [how can I achieve data locality](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/faq/#how-can-i-achieve-data-locality) section in the connector documentation for more information on configuration options.
- **Indexes**

  Remove indexes before inserting the data and rebuild them after. When inserting mass amounts of data, users have found performance improvements by removing indexes at the start of the process and then building them just once at the end. For example:

  ```
  val writeConfig = WriteConfig(mongoDbOptions)
  MongoConnector(writeConfig.asOptions).withCollectionDo(writeConfig, {
    coll: MongoCollection[Document] => coll.dropIndex("index")
  })

  MongoSpark.write(sourceValueDf)
            .options(writeConfig.asOptions)
            .mode(SaveMode.Append)
            .save()

  MongoConnector(writeConfig.asOptions).withCollectionDo(writeConfig, {  
    coll: MongoCollection[Document] => coll.createIndex(...)
  })
  ```
- **Write concern**

  Writing to the primary node only and not waiting for replication improves speed at the cost of redundancy. This can be configured via the `WriteConfig` / `mongoDbOptions`. See the [Output  configuration documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/configuration/#output-configuration).

What is the load on the MongoDB machine(s) when you are running this job? Is it the bottleneck? Systems like [MongoDB Cloud Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/cloud-manager) provide full performance visibility and monitoring to help you understand what is happening at the MongoDB layer.

## Improving MongoDB and Spark performance

In short there is no panacea or magic configuration option to help improve performance. It will take debugging, understanding of the issue at hand and potentially considered configuration of both Spark and MongoDB clusters. Together, they have already been shown to provide [very fast compute and storage](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-and-apache-spark-at-china-eastern-airlines) but it depends on the usage and each system working together.

The first steps are to use the available monitoring tools to understand where the bottleneck(s) are.

Comment: Ross is correct, you should take a look at Cloud Manager, or even mongostat/mongotop to see if mongodb is maxed or simply idling. Then you can get an idea of whether you need to tweak the software configuration or whether you need to adjust the hardware/architecture configuration.